# What is the probability to have an empty graph?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a **Random Graph R**. : assume the following:

If G=(V,E).   **V=10** vertices. and the probability to connect any **2** edges e is **p**.
Then what is the probability to get an empty graph (no edges) between any two nodes.

[image]

*My solution:*

As I think **Pr(empty)=(1-p)^10** . Am I right?
Is there any model/formula or equation for this kind of Graphs?

Comment: No. The probability of each *edge* is $p$. You assumed the probability of each *vertex* was $p$. ...  And what exactly do you mean by "Are there any models or formulas or equations for this kind of graph?"

Comment: just what is the correct answer please? is it Pr=(1-p)^(10 choose 2)

Comment: Here, $(1-p)^{45}$, since there are ${10\choose 2}=45$ possible edges. (Of course, that's assuming you're not allowing loops ...)

Comment: OK, you are right.. So the second part of my question is what is the output of Random Graph ?

Comment: It's an empty graph in this case.

Comment: OK, and in general ? what is the output ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph#Random_graph_models .